# How to Upgrade TLS version in CakePHP 2.2.1?

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, cakephp-2.2, tls1.2

I am using ***cakePHP2.2.1*** and ***PHP5.3.10***.And i have updated *curl* and *libcurl* now curl is supporting **TLS 1.2** in *terminal*. But when i am trying to send *curl* request in ***cakePHP*** it's shows the **TLS** version as **1.1**. Is there anyway to configure **TLS**  in ***cakePHP***?

Comment: CakePHP code will uses whatever curl version is available through PHP's curl functions. So your issue doesn't have anything to do with CakePHP itself.

Comment: @ADmad I also hope so. but my php-curl is using TLS 1.2 when i trying the same from out of cakePHP